# Enumeration in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

while executing this below lines i got an error.  Error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Help me to solve this.

```
Dim i As IEnumerator
    Dim item As DataGridItem
    Dim bChk As Boolean = False
    i = dgOfferStatus.Items.GetEnumerator
    For Each item In dgOfferStatus.Items
        i.MoveNext()
        item = i.Current
        item = CType(i.Current, DataGridItem)
        Dim chkItemChecked As New CheckBox
        chkItemChecked = CType(item.FindControl("chkItemChecked"), CheckBox)
        If chkItemChecked.Checked = True Then
            Try
                bChk = True
                lo_ClsInterviewProcess.JobAppID = item.Cells(1).Text
                lo_ClsInterviewProcess.candId = item.Cells(9).Text
                Dim str, strSchedule1, strSchedule As String
                Dim dspath As DataSet
                Dim candidateId As Integer
                ''Moving the resume to Completed folder

                ObjInterviewAssessment = New ClsInterviewAssessment
                dspath = ObjInterviewAssessment.GetOffComPath(CInt(lo_ClsInterviewProcess.JobAppID), "GetHoldPath")
                If dspath.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    If Not IsDBNull(dspath.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)) Then
                        str = dspath.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
                        strSchedule1 = str.Replace("Hold", "Completed")
                    End If
                End If

                Dim str1 As String
                str1 = Server.MapPath(str).Trim
                strSchedule = Server.MapPath(strSchedule1).Trim

                Dim file1 As File
                If file1.Exists(str1) Then
                    If file1.Exists(strSchedule) Then
                        file1.Delete(strSchedule)
                    End If

                    file1.Move(str1, strSchedule)
                End If
                ''
                intResult = lo_ClsInterviewProcess.UpdateApproveStatus(Session("EmployeeId"), strSchedule1)
                BindHoldGrid()
                If intResult > 0 Then


                    Alert.UserMsgBox("btnsearch", "Status Updated")
                Else
                    Alert.UserMsgBox("btnsearch", "Status not Updated")
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                ExceptionManager.Publish(ex)
                Throw (ex)
            End Try
        End If
    Next
    If bChk = False Then
        Alert.UserMsgBox("btnsearch", "Please Select any Candidate")
    End If
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    ExceptionManager.Publish(ex)
    'End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you reformat this post as it is not being displayed properly thanks

Comment: Also it may be helpful to break it down a bit and tell us which line of code is causing the error. To be honest you will get a better response if you help us a little!

Answer (score 4):

Look at this part of your code. I think it's what causes your exception.

```
Dim i As IEnumerator
...
Dim item As DataGridItem
...
i = dgOfferStatus.Items.GetEnumerator
For Each item In dgOfferStatus.Items
    i.MoveNext()
    item = i.Current  ' <-- here be dragons!? '
    ...
Next
```

What you're doing seems a little strange. You iterate through the same collection (`dgOfferStatus.Items`) twice, once with the `For Each` loop, and once manually using the `i` iterator. Then you modify items in your collection with `item = i.Current`. I believe it's this assignment that causes the exception.

(I also don't understand why you would do this. This assignment seems to be completeley superfluous, since `i.Current` and `item` should be identical since both iterators are at the same position in the collection.)

The exception basically tries to tell you that **you may not modify a collection while you are iterating through it**. But you seem to be doing exactly that.

Comment: Perhaps he meant to have i.Current = item (woops)